# log4cxx undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*)'

Tags: c++, netbeans, undefined-reference, log4cxx

I've got 2, according to me, identical cpp projects under Ubuntu Netbeans.

1. LoggerTestProject
2. CppApplication2

In the mainfiles of both I've integrated the following code:

```
The result of compiling the first Project is:
#include "log4cxx/logger.h"
#include "log4cxx/basicconfigurator.h"
#include "log4cxx/propertyconfigurator.h"

#include "ratio.h" //only in LoggerTestProject

#include <cstdlib>

#define LOGCONF "./cfg/log4cxx.properties"


using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;

//extern LoggerPtr logger; //ahaha! AOP should be useful here
LoggerPtr logger(Logger::getLogger("LoggerTestProject"));


//using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int inVar1 = 0;
LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, "Begin of LoggerTestProject");
```

Compiling the first one leads to a success:

```
cd '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/LoggerTestProject'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/LoggerTestProject'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/loggertestproject
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/LoggerTestProject'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/9bc1829f
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/9bc1829f/ratio.o.d"
g++ -fpermissive   -c -g -I/usr/include/log4cxx -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/9bc1829f/ratio.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/9bc1829f/ratio.o /home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/LoggerTestProject/ratio.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d"
g++ -fpermissive   -c -g -I/usr/include/log4cxx -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++ -fpermissive    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/loggertestproject build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/9bc1829f/ratio.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o -llog4cxx
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/LoggerTestProject'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/LoggerTestProject'
```

wherelse compiling the second one to a failure:

```
cd '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_2
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_2 build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*)'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Logger>::~ObjectPtrT()':
/usr/include/log4cxx/helpers/objectptr.h:102: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase::~ObjectPtrBase()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN7log4cxx7helpers10ObjectPtrTINS_6LoggerEEE[_ZTIN7log4cxx7helpers10ObjectPtrTINS_6LoggerEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_2' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_2] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/uwez/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Has anyone got an idea what it could be? The /cfg - folder, which contains the log4cxx.properties file was not present in the second project, so I copied it manually. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In netbeans 8.2 in the menue open *File/project properties*.

click on *C++ Compiler* and add the path of the *log4cxx library* to the include Directories. In this case its */usr/include/log4cxx*, but it wasn't actually necessary for building the project.

For building the project it's absolutely necessary to go to *linker/libraries* and add *log4cxx*. In the browse window I had to open the folder */usr/lib32* and type *log4cxx.so*. This is the includefile that is needed to build the project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the Makefile used in the second project. My guess is that it  does not mention Log4cxx (e.g. does not have a -Llog4cxx).
The log4cxx.properties is used when you run the program, it does not get used when you build the program.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. So How can I solve the problem now? How can I make it have a -Llog4cxx?

Comment: Are you committed to using NetBeans? Its support for C++ is not good. Perhaps consider using VSCode, or if you are command line comfortable conan+cmake - see  https://ilyas-hamadouche.medium.com/c-package-management-with-conan-introduction-8c7bd928c009